# Sed replace on a pattern after another specific pattern match?

Tags: linux, sed, replace, pattern-matching

I have a file that has multiple similar patterns, each delimited by unique headers on preceding lines.

I would like to match/replace the `pattern` string only after `header3` in this example:

```
header1
a
b
pattern
c

header2
a
b
c
d
pattern

header3
a
pattern
b
c
d
```

In my actual file, there may be any number of header strings, and any number of lines in between. So, the number of lines before or after the `header3` match cannot be defined.

(Additionally, this machine does not have the gnu sed binary available, so this is not an option that can be used.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an answer to my own question using an address range:

`sed -i -r '/header3/,/pattern/ s|pattern|replacement|' filename`

Comment: [facepalm] That is better. I'll delete my answer.